# Book suggestion. (Strongly correlated electron systems)

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, strong-correlated

Can anyone suggest a good book on strongly correlated electron systems which may be starts off with second quantization, goes through Hubbard model, Mott transition, T-J model etc? I have the book by Patrick Fazekas but I want a more fundamental and comprehensive book suitable for a beginner in this field.

Comment: Would you prefer a book that approaches the topic from integrability (Quantum inverse scattering, Bethe ansatz, etc.) or a less deep introduction. The former approach can get really heavy on the mathematics (quantum groups) and requires knowing a fair bit about integrability.

Comment: Why not starting with Eduardo Fradkin, Field Theory of Condensed Matter Physics, Cambridge (for the second edition, 2013), and see what you are interested in from this book. Other books on the same topics are the book by A. Tsvelik or the book by A. Altland and B. Simons, with almost the same title (all contain *field theory* and *condensed matter* in their title). The book by X.G. Wen is also interesting, but cover less topics of your interest than the previous ones (it has a similar title as well).

Comment: I think I don't have that background as of now to start with that kind of text.But eventually I will have to come to that.I think I'd prefer a less deep introduction as of now @G.Bergeron

Comment: @Annie May I ask what is your background in math and physics? Do you have a background in condensed matter per se?

Comment: I have done my Master's in Physics,and presently I'm starting my PhD work in theoretical condensed matter physics.I have done 2 courses on condensed matter physics in my Master's. @ G.Bergeron

Comment: @Annie Ok, I will try and compile a selection of material that bring you from basic condensed matter/QFT to the topic in question. I will try to slowly approach integrability theory because I think it would be necessary in strongly interacting systems, where it not for numerical approaches. The Fock states from the free theory are basically useless and outside of integrable models enabling the creation of a new useful Fock space, I am not sure what can be done.